# The dimension of the homogeneous coordinate ring of a projective variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

> ***Theorem.*** Let $Y$ be a projective variety with homogeneous coordinate ring $S(Y)$, then $$\dim S(Y)=\dim Y+1$$

I have broken down the proof into steps. The various steps I have shown them and there are no problems, except in the final step.

Consider the multiplicative subset $$T_i=\{x_i^r+I(Y)_r\;:\; r\ge 0\}\subseteq S(Y)$$ consisting of homogeneous elements. The homogeneous localization $$S(Y)_{x_i}:=T_i^{-1} S(Y)$$ is defined by $$S(Y)_{x_i}=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\big(S(Y)_{x_i}\big)_n,$$ where
$$\big(S(Y)_{x_i}\big)_n:=\{a/s\;:\;a\in S(Y)_{n+r}, s\in T_i\cap S(Y)_r\;\text{for same}\; r\ge 0\}$$

**Step 1:** Consider the homeomorphism $\varphi_i\colon U_i\to \mathbb{A}^n$ given by $$\varphi([a_0:\dots :a_n])=(a_0,\dots,a_{i-1}, a_{i+1},\dots a_n).$$ The set $Y_i:=\varphi_i(Y\cap U_i)\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ is an affine variety. Now consider the coordinate ring $A(Y_i)=A/I(Y_i)$, where $A=k[y_1,\dots, y_n]$. I proved that:
$$
\boxed{A(Y_i)\cong \big(S(Y)_{x_i}\big)_0}
$$

**Step 2.** Suppose that $x_i\notin I(Y)$, then $$
\boxed{\big(S(Y)_{x_i}\big)_0[x_i,x_i^{-1}]\cong S(Y)_{x_i}}
$$

**Step 3.** If $x_i\notin I(Y)$, then $x_i$ is transcendental over $K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)$, here $K(R)$ denote the quotient field of the integral domain $R$.

**Concluding step**: From $\color{red}{\text{step 2}}$ we have

$$K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)(x_i)\color{red}{\cong}K(S(Y)_{x_i})\color{green}{\cong}K(S(Y))$$ For the congruence in green click  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194894/localization-and-field-of-quotients)

> **Question 1.** I did not understand the first term of the previous expression. $$K\big(\big(S(Y)_{x_i}\big)_0[x_i,x_i^{-1}]\big)\cong K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)(x_i)$$ why?

Now we see that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dim S(Y) =&\;\text{tr.}\deg_kK(S(Y))\\
=&\;\text{tr.}\deg_kK((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)(x_i)\\
\color{blue}{=}&\; 1+\text{tr.}\deg K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

> **Question 2** Why the blue equality holds? I know that this holds from step 3, but I don't understand why it is like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: since $(S(Y)_{x_i})_0[x_i,x_i^{-1}]\hookrightarrow K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)(x_i)$ and the latter is a field, we get an injection $\iota$ from the fraction field of the LHS to the RHS. We now need to show that this is surjective. Any element of the RHS can be written as $$\frac{\sum p_jx_i^j}{\sum q_kx_i^k}\in K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)(x_i)$$ where $p_j,q_k\in K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)$, so it suffices to show that $\sum p_jx_i^j$ and $\sum q_kx_i^k$ are in the image of the map from $K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0[x_i,x_i^{-1}])$. But this is clear: each $p_j$ and $q_k$ is in the image of the map from $K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)\subset K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0[x_i,x_i^{-1}])$, and $x_i$ is clearly in the image of $\iota$ too.

Question 2: This is just the fact that transcendence degree adds over field extensions. Given a tower of field extensions $F_1\subset F_2\subset F_3$, we have $\operatorname{trdeg}_{F_1} F_3=\operatorname{trdeg}_{F_1} F_2 + \operatorname{trdeg}_{F_2} F_3$. Take $F_1=k$, $F_2=K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)$, and $F_3=K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)(x_i)$: as $x_i$ is transcendental over $K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)$, we have that $F_3$ is a transcendence degree one extension of $F_2$ and we're done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the discourse concerning the first question a general fact? Could you please write it down in general? Maybe the notations are simpler and I can apply it to other observations.

Comment: Which part? The first sentence is just the universal property of localization/fraction fields, the next claim is the structure of $F(t)$, and then finally we just use the fact that if we want to show some combination of elements is in the image of our homomorphism, it suffices to show each element individually is.

Comment: $K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)(x_i)$ I don't understand who this field is in general

Comment: Well, luckily you don't have to understand much about it here. The key point is that it's of the form $F(t)$ for $F$ some field (in this case $K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)$) and some indeterminate $t$ which is transcendental over $F$ (in this case $x_i$). Elements of $F(t)$ have a particularly nice description: they're rational functions in $t$ with coefficients from $F$. This is all we use in the argument.

Comment: a last question, why $$(S(Y)_{x_i})_0[x_i,x_i^{-1}]\hookrightarrow K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)(x_i)$$?

Comment: Well, $(S(Y)_{x_i})_0$ injects in to $K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)$, right? This gives an injective map $(S(Y)_{x_i})_0[x_i]\to K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)[x_i]$ just as any injection $R\to F$ gives an injection $R[x]\to F[x]$, and then we can localize both sides to get an injective map $(S(Y)_{x_i})_0[x_i,x_i^{-1}]\to K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)[x_i,x_i^{-1}]$ and embed the last thing in to its field of fractions $K((S(Y)_{x_i})_0)(x_i)$.

Comment: when you said that we can localize both sides do you intend to localize in $x_i$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: If $R$ is a domain and we consider $K(R)[x,x^{-1}]$, then $K(K(R)[x,x^{-1}])=K(R)(x)$?

Comment: Yes. Clearly, $K(R)[x,x^{-1}]$ embeds in to $K(R)(x)$, so it's field of fractions is contained in $K(R)(x)$. On the other hand, elements of $K(R)(x)$ are rational functions in $x$ with coefficients from $K(R)$ so you can get any such element as the quotient of two polynomials in $x$ with coefficients from $K(R)$, giving that its field of fractions is all of $K(R)(x)$.